# Shapeless: Abstracting over * arity and get return type as tuple of inner abstract type members

Tags: scala, shapeless

```
abstract class Test[T] {
  type Value
}

// This is wrong with respect to Scala syntax.
def fun(tests: Test[_]*): Tuple(tests(0)#Value, tests(1)#Value) = {
}
```

What I want is an arity abstraction over the arbitrary number of var args where the type is held by the abstract type member `Value`, as seen above. E.g go from any arity to Product, go from Product to a HList or whatever and then from that to the tuple.

```
def test[F, A, L, S, Rc <: Test[_]](f: F)(implicit ftp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, L => S],
  ev: S <:< Seq[Rc#Value]) {

  val sq = ev(ftp(f))

  // now I'd like to build a type to reference the return sequence in a tuple
  // What is the real way to do the below?
  type ReturnTpe = sq.foldLeft(HNil)((l, col) => col#Value :: l).tupled
}
```